# no such filter, when using filter complex with pre-scale

Tags: ffmpeg

the desired output is combining 3 vids, and using scale or pad (do some processing on the input).

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i in2.mkv -i in3.mkv \
-filter_complex "[0:v][v0];[1:v]scale=-1:1440[v1];[2:v][v2],[v0][v1][v2]hstack=inputs=3"
 -map "[v]" -map 1:a output.mp4
```

give:

> [AVFilterGraph @ 0xec0a80] No such filter: ''
> Error initializing complex filters.
> Invalid argument

Comment: What are `[0:v][v0];` and `[2:v][v2],` meant to do?

Comment: there is the confusing part, the pattern on filtergraph, [in]opt_preprocess[out]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0:v][v0]` and `[2:v][v2]` don't contain any filter declaration, and thus ffmpeg complains. Insert whichever filter is desired in between the input and output pads.

I suppose you meant to scale the heights of the 3 inputs to match. In which case,

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i in2.mkv -i in3.mkv \ -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:1440[v0];[1:v]scale=-1:1440[v1];[2:v]scale=-1:1440[v2];[v0][v1][v2]hstack=inputs=3" -map "[v]" -map 1:a output.mp4`

on input processing with -filter_complex, you use this pattern:

`[input_number:v]operation[tmp_output_name]`

Comment: I suggest an edit, please take a look.